# How to bind/merge prcomp and predict data in r?

Tags: r, pca, ggbiplot

To plot a predicted validation/test data set within a training dataset in ggbiplot as addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603268/how-to-plot-training-and-test-validation-data-in-r-using-ggbiplot), I would like to bind/merge the two datasets.

The given mwe is:

```
library(ggbiplot)
data(wine)

##pca on the wine dataset used as training data
wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)

##add the wine.classes as a column to the dataset
wine$class <- wine.class

##simulate test data by generating three new wine classes
wine.new.1 <- wine[c(sample(1:nrow(wine), 25)),]
wine.new.2 <- wine[c(sample(1:nrow(wine), 43)),]
wine.new.3 <- wine[c(sample(1:nrow(wine), 36)),]

##Predict PCs for the new classes by transforming 
#them using the predict.prcomp function
pred.new.1 <- predict(wine.pca, newdata = wine.new.1)
pred.new.2 <- predict(wine.pca, newdata = wine.new.2)
pred.new.3 <- predict(wine.pca, newdata = wine.new.3)

##simulate the classes for the new sorts
wine.new.1$class <- rep("new.wine.1", nrow(wine.new.1))
wine.new.2$class <- rep("new.wine.2", nrow(wine.new.2))
wine.new.3$class <- rep("new.wine.3", nrow(wine.new.3))
```

And I've been using:

```
df.train.pred <- rbind(wine.pca$x, pred.new.1, pred.new.2, pred.new.3)
```

to fuse the two but ggbiplot returned an error as it *Expected a object of class prcomp, princomp, PCA, or lda*

How can I consolidate the two so they become an object ggbiplot accepts?

Comment: `prcomp(wine, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)` yields `Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric`

Comment: Oups sorry correct version of that line is `wine.pca <- prcomp(wine[,-14], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)` or add the wine.classes to the data set after the prcomp,  just revised that in the above version!